# Q.Promise and KO.mapping not Converting Array of Objects to Proper Type

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, typescript, q

I am trying to filter an observable array but am running into issues due what I believe is the ko.utils.arrayFilter method changing all my model's field names to lowercase. I should note Typescript is being used in this project.

This is my Model:

```
    export class MyListModel {
    constructor(jsObject?: {}) {
        if (jsObject) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(jsObject, {}, this);
        }
    }
    Text = ko.observable<string>();
    Value = ko.observable<string>();
}
```

In my viewModel I have the following field:

```
  inches = ko.observableArray<Models.MyListModel>([]);
```

In another part of the program I call the filterInches() method to filter the array given some criteria. The value parameter is the currently selected value in a dropdown.

```
    filterInches(value) {

        if (value == 6) {
            var filtered = ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.inches(),
                function (item) {

                    if (parseInt(item.Text()) <= 8)
                        return true;
                });

            this.filteredInches(filtered);
        } else {
            this.filteredInches(this.inches());
        }
    }
```

No errors are thrown at compile time but when I run the application in the browser I get an error saying "item.Text is not a function". When I step through the code in Chrome it looks like item is converted to an anonymous object with a text and value field. The fields are now lowercase which I think is causing the problems I'm running into. What could be causing this behavior?

**EDIT:** 
I'm working with a different but related part of this code and I think I'm starting to see why it's not working. I believe it has something to do with the Q Promise library but I don't understand enough about this library to figure out why it's not working(yes, I read the documentation). I think the devs that wrote this code didn't realize that it's not doing what they think it's doing.

The first thing I've tried in order to verify that something is wrong is to modify the property names of our model:

```
    export class MyListModel {
constructor(jsObject?: {}) {
    if (jsObject) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(jsObject, {}, this);
    }
}
  Cat = ko.observable<string>();
  Chicken = ko.observable<string>();
}
```

Now, if we go back to a revised filterInches() method we will see that item.Cat works at compile time but when I step through the code in Chrome the item object actually has no property called Cat(it's undefined). Its properties are still text and value:

```
    filterInches(value) {

    if (value == 6) {
        var filtered = ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.inches(),
            function (item) {

                if (parseInt(item.Cat()) <= 8)
                    return true;
            });

        this.filteredInches(filtered);
    } else {
        this.filteredInches(this.inches());
    }
}
```

This tells me that the objects we're retrieving from json are not getting mapped to MyListModel objects. I believe the MyListModel class itself is fine though.

The problem I think is arising from the code that gets the inches in the first place:

```
    refreshInches() {
        this.DataService.getInches().done(entities => {
            this.inches(entities);
        });
    }
```

and then the getInches() method is as follows:

```
    getInches(): Q.Promise<Array<Models.MyListModel>> {
        return Q($.getJSON(this._baseUrl + 'GetInches'));
    }
```

I think the original intent for this code was to get the inches data asynchronously from an endpoint and convert the json data to MyListModel objects. As I said earlier, I'm not familiar enough with Q.Promise to know what could be wrong with the getInches() method. It's pretty clear to me though that it's simply returning an array of anonymous objects from the JSON data.

For reference the json objects being returned from the endpoint look like this:

```
[{"text":"0","value":"0"},{"text":"1","value":"1"},...]
```

Anyone know how the getInches() method can be improved to do what it's supposed to do?

Comment: KnockoutJS is open source, I've checked [the `arrayFilter` source code](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/utils.js#L149) but found that it doesn't do any lowercasing. At any rate, we'd need a [mcve] to be able to help, any chance you could try to make one (e.g. by including the full code, if helpful/possible compiled javascript or failing that full TS code)?

Comment: "parseInt(item.Text)" returns NaN if "item.Text" is defined as "Text = ko.observable<string>();"

Comment: That line should probably be `parseInt(item.Text(), 10)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code, getInches is supposed to return a `Q.Promise<Array<Models.MyListModel>>`, i.e. a promise for an array of `MyListModel` objects.

However, in its current form:

```
getInches(): Q.Promise<Array<Models.MyListModel>> {
    return Q($.getJSON(this._baseUrl + 'GetInches'));
}
```

it does not do that. The above returns a promise for `<whatever the server gives you>`, in this case apparently an array of plain objects.

To change it so it matches the supposed type, we could do

```
getInches(): Q.Promise<Array<Models.MyListModel>> {
    var jqXhr = $.getJSON(this._baseUrl + 'GetInches');

    return Q(jqXhr).then(data => {
        return data.map(item => {
            return new Models.MyListModel(item);
        });
    });

    // or, if you must
    return Q(jqXhr).then(data => data.map(item => new Models.MyListModel(item)));
}
```

So now we can store the freshly created `MyListModel` instances in an observable:

```
refreshInches() {
    this.DataService.getInches().done(this.inches);
}
```

Note that `this.inches` is an observable, and observables are functions, which allows us to directly use it as a callback.

A function which is used as promise handler will receive the promised value as its first argument. An observable will store the value of the first argument you call it with, so this fits nicely.

---

Additionally, your `filteredInches` approach is too complicated. Instead of making it a function that you need to call, make it a computed that depends on some observable in your viewmodel. This way it will never be inconsistent with the rest.

```
this.filteredInches = ko.pureComputed(() => {
    var value = this.value();

    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.inches(), item => {
        value != 6 || +item.Text() <= 8;
    });
});
```

---

Looking at your viewmodel creation, you would probably want to have a numeric observable (or computed) somewhere so that you don't need to do remember to type-convert the `Text` property in calculations.

Comment: Hey @Tomalak thank you so much for the very detailed response. It's been very helpful. I think I am 99% of the way there! I got as far as applying your changes to getInches() and refreshInches() and the json is sort of getting mapped to my model.  The array of MyModel objects is getting populated  with the following props: Cat : observable(), Chicken : observable(), text : observable(), value : observable(). `This.inches()[0].Cat()` returns "undefined" but `this.inches()[0].text()` returns "0" which is the value I need.

Comment: Yes, that's how the mapping plugin works. Given no additional options (as in this case) it maps all properties of the input object into observables on the target viewmodel. An input object `{text: "bla"}` will be turned into an object `{text: ko.observable("bla")}`. The observables your target viewmodel already has (`Cat`) will either be populated (if their name matches) or left alone. Since there is no `Cat` in the input object, the `Cat` in the viewmodel will stay undefined. Apparently though there is a `text` in the input, which will get mapped into your viewmodel, so this is what you see.